# Making kubectl private in AWS-EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, amazon-eks

I want to create a cluster which is very similar to this one where they are using azure.
[Link to the tutorial](https://medium.com/devops-dudes/how-to-setup-completely-private-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-clusters-with-azure-private-links-b800a5a6776f)

Whatever tutorials i have gone through for AWS-EKS are blocking it bi directional. But I need a bastion host and don't want the application to be inaccessible via www.

Is there a possible solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The AKS tutorial you posted aim to create completely Private Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

Anyway, either case you can use [eksctl](https://eksctl.io/introduction/) to easily create one, here's a quick example where public access to control plane is disabled and allow node group to use NAT for Internet access. You can replace <> with your own preference:

```
cat << EOF | eksctl create cluster -f - 
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name: <my cluster name>
  region: <my region name>
vpc:
  clusterEndpoints:
    privateAccess: true
    publicAccess: false
nodeGroups:
  - name: <my self-managed node group name>
    instanceType: <t3a.medium>
    desiredCapacity: 1
EOF
```

Comment: As per the above link "eksctl supports creation of fully-private clusters that have no outbound internet access and have only private subnets". And I don't want that. I want the outbound internet access. Just want to block kubectl to outbound internet.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to access your containers from outside aws, but not your control plane?

Comment: Updated where public access to control plane is disabled while the node group uses NAT for Internet access.